# arduino adding leading and trailing zeros

Tags: arduino

I have a float number ranging from 0.001 up to 999.999 The question: how I can format all the range numbers like this:

0.001 becomes 000.001

0.002 becomes 000.002

0.2 becomes 000.200

1.001 becoes 001.001

9.090 becomes 009.090

99.100 becomes 099.100

I recently asked this question as C++ and got nice answers but was unable to convert the answers into arduino code , thanks

Comment: Arduino is programmed in C++, so your question doesn't make too much sense if you already know solutions in C++.

Comment: you also might want to add your code and explain what you observe when running it on Arduino.

Comment: The c++ solution is sprintf, but that doesn't work due to microcontroller handling of float to string.

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem?

Comment: Hi , thanks alot for the help, from the code you wrote I took the idea of converting the number into a string and then I did string manipulation to concat the string with "0" from left and right . I did it using for loop , I learned that numbers such as float do not store extra leading zeros in the left of number , so I had to convert the number into string.and it seems working fine, thanks guys much love and respect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sprintf was my first thought but seems to not work well on arduino for floats: https://www.reddit.com/r/arduino/comments/2fum7c/sprintf_outputs_a_question_mark_when_i_try_to/

The below code pads left zeros, but does not work for negative numbers, if negative numbers are required you would need to write something to left-shift the negative sign after padding.

Here is some Example code:

```
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available() == 0){return;}
  char buff[20];
  float testNumber = Serial.parseFloat();
  Serial.read();
  int stringLength = 7;
  int decimalPrecision = 3;

  dtostrf( testNumber, stringLength, decimalPrecision, buff );
  padZeros(buff);
  leftShiftNegative(buff);

  //clamp max size
  String clampedOutput;
  for(int i = 0;i<7;i++)
  {
    clampedOutput+= buff[i];
  }
  
  Serial.println(clampedOutput);
  delay(1000);
}

void padZeros(char* charStr) //this doesn't handle negative numbers
{
  for (int i = 0; i < strlen(charStr); i++)
  {
    if (charStr[i]==' ')
      charStr[i]='0';
    else
      break;
  }
}

void leftShiftNegative(char* charStr)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < strlen(charStr); i++)
  {
    if (charStr[i]=='-')
    {
      charStr[i]='0';
      charStr[0] = '-';
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, had a mistake in my original answer, I edited and corrected the arguments of dtostrf to include the buffer argument. (also added padZeros)

Comment: Tested it for all of your presented values and it produced the desired results.

Comment: Dont you think I can do it in two phases : add trailing zeros and then adding leading zeros ? I will need this to give a fixed length for dht22 output and this sensor will produce positive and negativd values

Comment: updated answer to clamp output to a fixed length and handle negative values.  Yes you could add the zeros by hand, but there are a lot of edge cases.